# Equivalence of $Spin^C$-Structures

Tags: principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I'm trying to understand the equivalence of $Spin^C(n)$-structures in the book "Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry" by Thomas Friedrich, p. 47 ff, but I got somehow stuck because I'm not so familiar with bundles. The setting goes as follows:

Let $Q$ be a principal $SO(n)$-bundle over a suitable base manifold $X$ and $Spin^C(n) = Spin(n) \times_{Z_2} S^1$.

A $Spin^C$-structure of $Q$ is a pair $(P,\Lambda)$, where $P$ is a $Spin^C(n)$-principal bundle over $X$ and $\Lambda : P \rightarrow Q$ and

$\begin{array}{ccc} P\times Spin^C(n) & \rightarrow &
 P \\\ \downarrow{\scriptstyle \Lambda \times \lambda} &&\downarrow{\scriptstyle\Lambda} \\\ Q\times SO(n) &\rightarrow &Q\end{array}$

commutes, where $\lambda : Spin^C(n)\rightarrow SO(n)$ is given by $\lambda[g,z] = \lambda(g)$.

We have $P/S^1 \simeq Q$ and $P_1 \simeq P/Spin(n)$ and thus a twofold covering $P\rightarrow Q \times P_1$ on the fiberwise product.

Now let $(P,\Lambda)$ and $(P^*,\Lambda^*)$ two $Spin^C$-structures of $Q$. The author gives two versions of what it means for the two structures to be equivalent:

1. There exists a bundle-isomorphism $\Phi :P \rightarrow P^*$ such that

$\begin{array}{ccc} 
P & \xrightarrow{\scriptstyle\Phi} & P^* \\
&{\scriptstyle\Lambda}\searrow \swarrow{\scriptstyle\Lambda^*} \\
&Q&
\end{array}$

commutes.

2. There exists a bundle isomorphism $\Phi:P\rightarrow P^*$ and a bundle isomorphism $\psi: P_1 \rightarrow P_1^*$ such that

$\begin{array}{ccc} P &\xrightarrow{\scriptstyle\Phi} &P^* \\
\downarrow &&\downarrow \\
Q\times P_1 &\xrightarrow{\scriptstyle Id\times\psi} &Q \times P_1^*
\end{array}$

commutes. My problem is, that I can't see in detail, why these two criteria are equivalent. How can one "construct" $\psi$ in the first case and $\Lambda$ in the second?

Comment: I guess there should  be a third diagram expressing that the composition of $P \to Q\times P_1$ with projection $P_1\times Q \to Q$ is $\Lambda.$